# Do not display popup when clicking Chrome Extension browser action button

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, dom-events

I want my Chrome extension to behave such that when a user clicks on the extension button, it sends a message and then closes the popup. I have nothing I want to display in the popup and ideally don't want it to even appear in the first place.

Half the time, my code works. The other half of the time, that little empty white bubble remains even after the message has been sent. Why is this non-determinism occurring? Is there a way to simply send a message on clicking the extension button and bypassing the pointless popup appearing?

Here is my popup.js:

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {

        // Go immediately to background script.
        // This popup's thread of execution will get killed as soon as we move to another tab.
        chrome.extension.sendRequest({
                tab: tabs[0],
                message: "Button was clicked"
        });
        window.close();
});
```

which is included in the following popup.html:

```
<head>
<script src="popup.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
```

My `manifest.json` (with irrelevant fields removed) is:

```
{
  "name": "My Extension",
  "description": "This is my extension",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
      "js": ["content.js"]
    }
  ],
  "background": { "scripts": ["background.js"] },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
        "http://*/*",
        "https://*/*",
        "tabs"
  ],
}
```

Comment: You just declared `default_popup` in `manifest.json`, that means once browser action is clicked, the `popup.html` will show up. If you don't want that, just remove that field and listen to `chrome.browserAction.onClicked`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just declared `default_popup` in `manifest.json`, that means once browser action is clicked, the `popup.html` will show up. If you don't want that, just remove that field and listen to `chrome.browserAction.onClicked` in `background.js`.

manifest.json

```
{
  ...
  "browser_action": {},
  ...
}
```

background.js

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({tab: tab, message: "Button was clicked"});
});
```

Comment: I think it works. Thank you. Man, these Chrome extensions are so fiddly.

Comment: @Sridhar-Sarnobat, "fiddly" meaning?

Comment: I don't remember. Maybe difficult to debug and counter intuitive.